# ESLint always throwing key-spacing error

Tags: vue.js, eslint

I have the following in my .eslintrc:

```
'key-spacing': [ 'error', {
    'singleLine': {
        'beforeColon'   : false,
        'afterColon'    : true
    },
    'multiLine': {
        'beforeColon'   : false,
        'afterColon'    : true,
        'align'         : 'colon'
    }
}]
```

The goal being to make sure in an object assignment that the following is true:

1. in a single line assignment, there is no space before each colon,
   but there is one after.
2. in a multi-line assignment, the colons line up horizontally, and
   there is a space both before and after each colon.

the strange thing is that the following three code snippets:

1 [ from my app.vue file ].

```
export default {
    name        : 'app',
    components  : {
        todos
    }
}
```

2 [ from my main.js file ].

```
new Vue({
    el      : '#app',
    render  : h => h( App )
})
```

3 [ from my Hello.spec.js file ].

```
const vm = new Vue({
    el      : document.createElement( 'div' ),
    render  : h => h( Hello )
})
```

are each throwing errors on the key-spacing eslint rule:

```
/Users/autoboxer/development/learning-vue/src/app.vue
    12:3  error  Missing space after key 'name'  key-spacing

/Users/autoboxer/development/learning-vue/src/main.js
    6:2  error  Missing space after key 'el'  key-spacing

/Users/autoboxer/development/learning-vue/test/unit/specs/Hello.spec.js
    7:4  error  Missing space after key 'el'  key-spacing
```

I can't figure out from my settings why they would be causing the errors listed as there are the requisite spaces after each specified word, but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Using tabs, perhaps?

Comment: I am using tabs.  What's weird is it only complains about the top line in each case.  All three files should throw two errors each, but the first object member is the only one it complains about.

Comment: That was the problem, I needed to align them using spaces instead of tabs.

Answer (score 4):

Configuration for this rule is really complex. I think what you are looking for is something like this:

```
'key-spacing': [ 'error', {
    'singleLine': {
        'beforeColon' : false,
        'afterColon'  : true
    },
    "align": {
        "beforeColon" : true,
        "afterColon"  : true,
        "on"          : "colon"
    }
}]
```

However, even with this configuration, ESLint doesn't allow for arbitrary location for colons. They have to be as close as possible to the longest key name in the object. So with the above configuration your code has to change to:

```
export default {
    name       : 'app',
    components : {
        todos
    }
}
```

That will lint correctly with configuration I provided.

Comment: Thanks Ilya, that was definitely half the problem I was facing.  The other half is that I was using tabs instead of spaces.  Because of the difficulty in determining alignment with tabs, they can't be used.  It's outlined in this issue: https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/1727